# Compare passing null int String and Integer constructors

Tags: java

Consider below two statements

```
    Integer integer = new Integer(null);
    String string = new String(null);
```

2nd one gives compilation error saying

```
Cannot resolve constructor `String(null)`
```

Now both Integer and String have constructors that accept `String`. So how come string ones give compilation error but not integer one.

As calling first one calls

```
  public Integer(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        this.value = parseInt(s, 10);
    }
```

so I am expecting string one also calls

```
 public String(String original) {
        this.value = original.value;
        this.hash = original.hash;
    }
```

I am not able to understand how that's happening and compiler is forced for compilation error in one but not other.

Comment: @all Thanks everyone , I think compiler should give some error like `ambiguous error` to be more precise.

Comment: What do you mean "*should*"? It **does**!

Comment: @all yes it gives, silly ide

Comment: The important thing that must be understood is `null` when passed to a method has no *type* associated with it.  In fact, `null` is a separate entity  / type in itself. The methods are bound during compile time and checked for signature match. Since `null` can be both `String` or `char[]`, in case of `String`, compiler screams

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String string = new String(null);
```

gives a different error to me.

It is an ambiguous call, since both the `public String(char value[])` and `public String(String original)` constructors match.

You can try :

```
String string = new String((String) null);
```

or

```
String string = new String((char[]) null);
```

to resolve the ambiguity.

On the other hand, the `Integer` class has just one constructor that takes a single reference type - `public Integer(String s)` - so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, specifically, that the call to `new String(null)` is ambiguous, meaning that there's more than one potential matching constructor so the compiler could not make the decision which one you want to invoke.

...and this is exactly what the standard Oracle java compiler already tells you:

```
Test.java:5: error: reference to String is ambiguous
        new String(null);
        ^
  both constructor String(StringBuffer) in String and constructor String(StringBuilder) in String match
1 error
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of `String string = new String(null);` there is ambiguity error.This constructor is ambiguous